# how to trigger code on certain elements? but it doesn't affect others

Tags: jquery, html

I want to display an alert if I select the "b" option, but before that, I'm in the "a" option, not from the "c" option.

```
<select>
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
</select>
```

Comment: what JS have you tried thus far?

Comment: $("option).click(function(){alert("show")})";

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, you want to only `alert` when the user clicks on `a` before clicking on `b`?

Comment: with nothing inside the function .. ?

Comment: there is a function

Comment: @DioSatriaDarma can we see said function

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a variable which holds the previous value that you were on. Using this variable you can check whether it was on "a" previously (`prev == "a"`).

See working example below:

```js
let prev = $('select').val();
$('select').change(function() {
  if(prev == 'a' && $(this).val() == 'b') { // Check if the previous value is 'a' and the current value is 'b'
    alert("From a ---> b");
  }
  prev = $(this).val();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>a</option>
  <option>b</option>
  <option>c</option>
</select>
```

Comment: you don't necessarily need to declare a variable - you can just get value on click, if value is b do action - unless I'm misunderstanding the question

Comment: I believe that's the case, to only trigger the event if a previous has occured

Comment: @treyBake I think OP wants it so that if you go from "a" then go to "b" it will display an alert. So if you went from "c" to "b" it wouldn't do anything

Comment: @NickParsons hmm I feel like the question is worded too loosely ... maybe I'm just not seeing it as clearly as others ... but hard to tell for me :/

Comment: can you simplify the coding? like $ ("option"). click (function () {alert ("a-> b")});

Comment: @treyBake yes, I agree, this is just how I interpreted the question. We'll see what the OP says I guess

Comment: what if I have 4 options, the trigger is from a to c?

Comment: @DioSatriaDarma What exactly do you mean...? If you had four options, `a, b, c, d` this would still work.

Comment: @DioSatriaDarma no worries, glad to help :)